# Fetch user roles and permissions for SharePoint Online using PnP

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm looking to fetch the SharePoint group roles and permissions using SharePoint-PnP for the Site Collection.

I was able to retrieve the SharePoint Groups using `$Web.SiteGroups` but failed to find the properties for fetching Roles and Permissions.

Using the following code snippet to retrieve Group ID, Title and Description.

```
#Import the required DLL
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
#OR
#Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
#Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'

#Mysite URL
$site = 'https://test.test.com/sites/sitename'

#Admin User Principal Name
$admin = 'LoginID'

#Get Password as secure String
#$password = Read-Host 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString 


#Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)

#Authenticate
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admin , $password)
$context.Credentials = $credentials

$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('ListName')

$web = $context.Web
$context.Load($web)
$context.Load($web.SiteGroups)
$context.Load($list)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($x in $web.SiteGroups)
{
    Write-Host $x.Id
    Write-Host $x.Title
    Write-Host $x.Description
}
$list.Update()
```

I don't have the option to go with the SharePoint Online DLL as I don't have the access to run the script as tenant administrator, but site collection administrator.

It would be helpful if this at all can be achieved using PnP ? Any other solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pnp script to get group role and permission in the site:

```
$cred = get-credential
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev" -Credentials $cred
$web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes RoleAssignments
foreach($ra in $web.RoleAssignments) {
    $member = $ra.Member
    $loginName = get-pnpproperty -ClientObject $member -Property LoginName
    $rolebindings = get-pnpproperty -ClientObject $ra -Property RoleDefinitionBindings
    write-host "$($loginName) - $($rolebindings.Name)"
    write-host  
}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer worked for me. Never knew this could be achieved so easily. Thanks for saving more million hours of mine.

Comment: Hey @Jerry_MSFT, Just a quick question, how would I be able to retrieve the group descriptions as well? As I couldn't find any property within RoleAssignments which can fulfill my requirement.